# Strongly typed drop down list using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to bind my drop down list from stored procedure,my query return two values CountryId and CountryName am stuck at the view.
My Model

```
public class RadioButton
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }

}
```

Action

```
public ActionResult RadioButton()
{
    var model = new RadioButton();
    List<RadioButton> result = db.Database.SqlQuery<RadioButton>("usp_countryname").ToList();      
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model MVCLearning.Models.RadioButton

@Html.DropDownList("dd",new SelectListItem(Model.CountryId,Model.CountryName))
```

On View Model.CountryId is DataValue Field and Model.CountryName is DataTextField what to pass before that.

Note : Radio Button action name and class name is just an example.

Stored Procedure.

```
select CountryId,CountryName from tblCountries
```

Have done this by ViewBag it works fine but want to do it with models.
Have posted a similar question but at that time my sql query was returning only one column.
 I looked for tutorial but didn't find one as per my requirement.

In Action

```
 model.Countries  = db.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<string>("select CountryId,CountryName from tblCountries").ToList();
```

I get error here. in SqlQuery<> what should be passed.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry for deleting the answer. Refer to http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/ways-to-bind-dropdown-list-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/binding-dropdownlist-in-mvc-in-various-ways-in-mvc-with-data/ The later should get you exactly what you are looking for.